# How can I use a regular expression to find a string of a certain length that contains no white space within it

Tags: php, regex

I want to use PHP's preg_replace to search a string for any substrings that are greater than 100 characters with no whitespace and replace it with nothing. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: By occupying yourself with RegExp basics …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/\s*\S{101}\S*\s*/`

This also removes the whitespace around the removed parts.